# YouTube videos in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, youtube, orchardcms

I have a `medialibrarypickerfield`, I've added a youtube video to it.

How can I get access to the YouTube video URL in an alternate at the following level:

`MediaLibraryPicker-ContentType-VideoFieldName.cshtml`

I've tried

```
var field = (MediaLibraryPickerField) Model.ContentField;
var contents = field.MediaParts;
```

to gain access to each `MediaPart`/video but when I iterate through the MediaParts, the MediaUrl is null. I know this has something to do with the `OEmbedPart` but I don't know how to access this.

Extremely frustrating so far. An otherwise very simple task outside of Orchard to store and retrieve URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the oEmbed part, just do `As<OEmbedPart>()` on the media part. You can then access the URL for the video by using the Source property of the part. You can also access a number of properties that are provided by the oEmbed site (YouTube in your case). Those properties can be accessed using the indexer on the part.

For example, `part["html"]` will give you the html code to embed in your page to render the video player:

```
@Html.Raw(part["html"])
```

There is also a "thumbnail" or a "thumbnail_url" property (depending on provider) that will give you the url of a thumbnail image. You can look at the whole blob of XML underlying that in the `Framework_ContentItemRecord` table's `Data` column. There is also a width and a height for example.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect better research I made on the subject.